# Connecting Behringer Footswitch to Cakewalk DAW

Tags: midi, guitar-effects, daw

I am using a Behringer FCB1010 midi foot controller and a Line 6 tone port UX2 audio interface (which my guitar is plugged into). While trying to assign a footswitch to a virtual pedal on cakewalk, an error occurs, saying that no midi input was detected. I have the FCB 1010 plugged straight into my laptop using a Midi to usb cable, is this ok or does it have to go through the audio interface? I am very new to all of this.

Comment: This should work but, on your computer, have you routed the midi signal to the virtual pedal?

Comment: @Tom, I've attempted to assign a switch to a pedal if that's what you mean? other than that, no.

Comment: IDK CakeWalk, nor MIDI handling on Windows, but the USB midi interface should give on your computer a MIDI port, that needs, somehow, to be connected/routed to the midi port of cakewalk.

Comment: I have selected the midi cable as my input but there is no option for output

Comment: I *think* you need to enable the cable in cakewalk, then set a midi track and arm the midi, then attach the amp-sim/pedal, then enable midi in the amp sim or pedal plugin.

Comment: @Yorik The actual pedal doesn't show up at all just the name of the cable